# Inconvertible types error

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, type-conversion

I want to do `menus.add(menuTemp);` but it shows `Inconvertible types error`. I tried `menus.add((Restaurant.Menu) menuTemp)`, this didn't work. Any suggestion?

```
add (java.util.List<oz.ncclife.model.Restaurant.Menu>)
to (java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>)
```

A part of project may help

```
ArrayList<String> menuTemp = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<Restaurant.Menu>> menus = new ArrayList<>();

//Change structure
ArrayList<Object> objPhones = new ArrayList<Object>();
for(int i = 0; i < phones.size(); i++)
{
        objPhones.add(phones.get(i));
}

ArrayList<Object> objMenus = new ArrayList<Object>();
for(int i = 0; i < menus.size(); i++)
{
         objMenus.add(menus.get(i));
}

tinydb.putListObject("restMenus",objMenus);
tinydb.putListObject("restPhones",objPhones);



//restore part
ArrayList<Object> objPhones = tinydb.getListObject("restPhones",Object.class);
ArrayList<Object> objMenus = tinydb.getListObject("restMenus",Object.class);

ArrayList<String> phoneTemp = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> menuTemp = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < objPhones.size(); i++)
{
            phoneTemp.add(objPhones.get(i).toString());
            menuTemp.add(objMenus.get(i).toString());
}
phones.add(phoneTemp);
menus.add(menuTemp);
```

Also, Restaurant.java

```
public class Restaurant
{
@SerializedName("cacheVersion")
@Expose
public String cacheVersion;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
public Integer id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
public String name;
@SerializedName("desc")
@Expose
public String desc;
@SerializedName("phones")
@Expose
public List<String> phones = null;
@SerializedName("menus")
@Expose
public List<Menu> menus = null;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
public String image;


public class Menu
{
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("foods")
    @Expose
    public List<Food> foods = null;
}


public class Food
{
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("desc")
    @Expose
    public String desc;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    public String price;
}
}
```

Comment: Suggestion 1: post the code where u use all this

Comment: It is a complicated situation :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't add

```
ArrayList<String> menuTemp = new ArrayList<>();
```

into this variable

```
List<List<Restaurant.Menu>> menus = new ArrayList<>();
```

because the compiler is waiting for a `List` of `Restaurant.Menu` not a `List` of `String`.

You should change the type of the `List` that you want to add like this way:

```
  List<Restaurant.Menu> menuTemp = new ArrayList<>();
```

> **UPDATE**

To add data to your `menuTemp` `ArrayList` you should us the constructor of the `Restaurant.Menu` class:

```
for(int i = 0; i < objPhones.size(); i++)
{
            phoneTemp.add(objPhones.get(i).toString());
            Restaurant.Menu menuClass = new Restaurant.Menu();
            menuClass.name = objMenus.get(i).toString();
            menuTemp.add(menuClass);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Change this :

```
ArrayList<Object> objMenus = tinydb.getListObject("restMenus",Object.class);
```

to this:

```
ArrayList<Menu> objMenus = tinydb.getListObject("restMenus",Menu.class);


for(int i = 0; i < objPhones.size(); i++)
    {
                phoneTemp.add(objPhones.get(i).toString());
                Restaurant.Menu menuClass = new Restaurant.Menu();
                menuClass.name = objMenus.get(i).name;
                menuTemp.add(menuClass);
    }
```

Comment: You are right but there is a different problem for this because also i use menuTemp.add(String value);

Comment: This is another question, but the solution is that you should use the constructor of your Restaurant.Menu class, like this: menuTemp.add(new Restaurant.Menu(....));

Comment: put your Restaurant.Menu class in the question

Comment: I added it as answer.

Comment: but objMenus has name and food object.

Comment: menuClass.name = objMenus.get(i).toString(); , name , what is the problem? I think my answer solve your question, you can mark it as resolved and ask another question

Comment: objMenus.get(i).toString() is not name. objMenus is object which has name and food object but you used it as name?

Comment: I don't know because you didn't put your "Object" class, update your question

Comment: Actually, I added all information :) I added Restaurant.Menu class as another post. Other part is above :)

Comment: Other side exploded :) I try to change it.

Comment: I noticed that If I change tinydb, I can not get that value. tinydb support ListObject, your logic is List<List<Menu.